# According to the holographic theory, can a boundary be an interior of another boundary?

Tags: spacetime, universe

Let's say that the holographic principle is true in this case.

So, is it possible that our 4D universe may have a 3D boundary, which has a 2D boundary, which has a 1D boundary - and that our 4D universe may be a boundary of a 5D space-time, which is a boundary of a 6D space-time... and so on?

Comment: To quote Wheeler:  *"the boundary of a boundary is zero"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible. Why exactly depends on your definition of "boundary":

The [topological boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) operator $\partial_\text{top}$ is (weakly) idempotent in the sense that $\partial_\text{top}^n = \partial_\text{top}^2$ for all $n \geq 2$, that is, the boundary of a boundary of a boundary is the same as the boundary of a boundary. This however, is not the notion of boundary that is usually meant when discussing the boundary of shapes.

More commonly, we use either the notion of [manifolds with boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary) or that of [homological boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_homology#Singular_chain_complex). In both cases, the boundary operator $\partial$ is nilpotent, i.e. $\partial^2 = 0$ - the boundary of a boundary is empty.